# AG-Grid - Checkbox at the cell level in raw Javascript

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

How can I create a checkbox at the cell level on ag-grid.

I did this:

```
function checkboxCellRenderer (params){
  var input = document.createElement("input")
  input.type = "checkbox";
  input.checked = params.value
  console.log(input)
  return input
}


{
    "headerName":"upload",
    "field":"e",
    "cellRenderer":"checkboxCellRenderer"
}
```

But how can I change the value when I check/uncheck the checkbox?

And how can I make to have the same styling as the default checkbox on ag-grid?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-binding-boolean-checkboxes-agcqjq?file=CheckboxRenderer.js)**

1. You can add a click listener to the input you've just created. And bind a method with it which can setData for that particular column, something like this

```
function checkboxCellRenderer (params){
  var input = document.createElement("input")
  input.type = "checkbox";
  input.checked = params.value
  console.log(input)
  this.checkedHandler = this.checkedHandler.bind(this);
  input.addEventListener('click', this.checkedHandler);
  return input
}

CheckboxRenderer.prototype.checkedHandler = function(e) {
  let checked = e.target.checked;
  let colId = this.params.column.colId;
  this.params.node.setDataValue(colId, checked);
}
```

2. To apply styling similar to ag-grid checkbox, you have to add classes that are being added to the original grid. This is the structure for the original checkbox.

[image]